# Attach UAC Manifest file to any PE using Update Resource

Tags: delphi, resources, uac

I want to build a simple tool to attach UAC manifest file to a given exe file the code works correctly but nothing happens.I must say that when i manually compile with the mainfest file it works ok.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
myRes:THandle;
test:PChar;
begin
test:='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+#13#10+
'<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">'+#13#10+
'<assemblyIdentity version="1.1.1.1"'+#13#10+
'processorArchitecture="X86"'+#13#10+
'name="[APP TO TEST WITH]"'+#13#10+ 
'type="win32"/>'+#13#10+
'<description>elevate execution level</description>'+#13#10+
'<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">'+#13#10+
'<security>'+#13#10+
'<requestedPrivileges>'+#13#10+
'<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>'+#13#10+
'</requestedPrivileges>'+#13#10+
'</security>'+#13#10+
'</trustInfo>'+#13#10+
'</assembly> ';
myRes := BeginUpdateResource('testuac.exe',false);
UpdateResource(myRes,MakeIntResource(24),'1',1033,test,length(test));
EndUpdateResource(myres,false);
ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;//Compiled with Delphi 7
```

The code works the resource appears inside the exe but it doesn't work . Any ideea why?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx - this explain how to make it from code. Also be aware of MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "IsUserAdmin.exe.manifest" line.

Comment: That line's not "how to make it from code," @RBA. That's how to define a .rc file to be compiled into a .res file, and the contents of that file are linked to a program at link time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would seem you can't give an arbitrary name to a manifest resource, try

```
UpdateResource(myRes,MakeIntResource(24),MakeIntResource(1),1033,test,length(test));
```

From winuser.h:

```
#define CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID MAKEINTRESOURCE( 1)
```

From [Specifying a Default Activation Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Resource ID 1
>   (CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID)
>   is activated implicitly when the .EXE
>   is executed.

Comment: The link for the documentation refers to a quote in the community content. The link that, that content refers ([RT_MANIFEST resource, and ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/06/26/rt-manifest-resource-and-isolation-aware-enabled.aspx))  from JunFeng Zhang's Microsoft blog, explains in more deatil..

Comment: @opc0de - With my tests it works.. You're putting an integer right; `MakeIntResource(1)`, *not* `MakeIntResource('1')`;

Comment: Sorry i didn't tested well because i messed up with the manifest but now i edited it and works great.Thanks very much mate